# Render page with new data after change Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form on 'products/add' and I add products to the database, after I submit the request, I redirect to the page where all the products are displayed. However, this page does not display information about the last item I added. How to fix it? How do I render pages after redirects to display the most current data?

'localhost:3333/products/add'

```
import React,  {useState} from 'react';
import api from './api';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'

const HandleProduct = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

  const updateName = (e) =>{
    setName(e.target.value);
  }
  const updateDescription = (e) =>{
    setDescription(e.target.value);
  }
  const addProduct = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const product = {
      name: name,
      description: description
    }
    api.addProduct(product)
    .then((req, res) =>{
      console.log(res);
      setRedirect(true);
    })
  }
  if(redirect) {
    return <Redirect to={'/products'} />
  }
return (
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={addProduct}>
            <input type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={updateName}/>
            <input type="text" name="description" value={description} onChange={updateDescription}/>
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  );
}
export default HandleProduct;
```

List of products(localhost:3333/products):

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {ProductsContext} from './ProductsContext';

const ProductsList = () => {
  const [data] = useContext(ProductsContext);
  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(data)}
        {data.products.map((product, index)=>(
            <div key={index}>
                <p>{product.name}</p>
                <p><i>{product.description}</i></p>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
export default ProductsList;
```

Comment: check your context is it reloading the records?

Comment: it is reloadind, data is displayed after the update(F5)